# MySQL isn't returning any error , yet the UPDATE command doesn't update anything

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is my query , it doesn't return any error on PHP MYADMIN but doesn't update anything .. any idea why ?  I researched but I have to do this in one query

```
UPDATE products_images SET image_sort = 1 WHERE products_id =6362 AND image_type ='products_video_xl_dynamic_2' AND image_type ='products_video_sm_dynamic_2'
```

Comment: Are you sure there are rows to update? Have you checked it with `SELECT`?

Comment: Yes, they are all in imagetype column

Comment: You cannot have tried `SELECT products_images WHERE products_id =6362 AND image_type ='products_video_xl_dynamic_2' AND image_type ='products_video_sm_dynamic_2'` because that will have returned 0 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the spellings and case of the String for image_type is correct

```
UPDATE products_images 
SET image_sort = 1 
WHERE products_id =6362 
AND image_type IN ('products_video_xl_dynamic_2', 'products_video_sm_dynamic_2')
```

You should add **OR** between the two image_type in **your own** query and it should work. Above query is MSSQL/SYBASE but do give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
image_type ='products_video_xl_dynamic_2' AND image_type ='products_video_sm_dynamic_2'
```

in the WHERE clause, image_type cannot be two things at the same time.

perhaps you want

```
(image_type ='products_video_xl_dynamic_2' OR image_type ='products_video_sm_dynamic_2')
```

to update each record that is either: xl OR sm

Comment: perhaps you want
`image_type ='products_video_xl_dynamic_2' OR image_type ='products_video_sm_dynamic_2'`
to update each record that is either: xl OR sm

Comment: The bit that is unsaid here is that an `UPDATE .. WHERE` that matches 0 records (because the match is impossible) will silently do nothing. There is no error because there is no error from a MySQL standpoint; there is a fault in the logic.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the headline question, you should be aware that `UPDATE .. WHERE` that matches 0 records will silently do nothing. Christopher has correctly identified that a match is impossible, which is why it does nothing. No rows match all the `WHERE` criteria, so no rows are updated.

But there is no error because there is no error from a MySQL standpoint; there is just a fault in your logic.